# Property getter and context manager

Tags: python, pandas, properties, decorator, contextmanager

I would like to define a property in such a way that whenever it is invoked, it is so done within a context manager. Say, I start with:

```
@property
def hangar(self):
    return self._hangar
```

and whenever down the code I write:

```
res = some_function(self.hangar)
```

I wish it to be evaluated as:

```
with pandas.HDFStore(...) as hangar:
    some_function(self.hangar)
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Um, what's `res` going to end up being? Can't you put that context-manager code in the getter definition? I'm not sure I'm understanding what you want.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga `res` is the result of some function operating on `hangar`, but `hangar` needs to be opened before the function is called and closed right afterwards.

Comment: You can't use a `property` to do what you want, since the getter method will be done running before `some_function` gets called. At best you could wrap the object that kept the context active until it was garbage collected, but the exact timing would be very uncertain (it might stay alive longer than you want). If you're using a context manager to ensure cleanup of something, you should be explicit and actually write out the `with` statement at the appropriate place.

Comment: @Blckknght thanks! i feared so.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you can see from the comments, what you need is somewhat "inside out" the usual way a context manager works.

But that does not stop you to make your function call/attribute retrieve "inside out" all the same: all you need is, instead of using 'property' call the desired method, passing the target function as  a parameter instead.

Something along this:

```
def context_property(method):
    def wrapper(self, target, *args, **kw):
        path = method(self)
        with pandads.HDFStore(path) as context:
            result = target(context, *args, **kw)
        return result
    return wrapper

class MyClass:
    @context_property
    def hangar(self):
        return "path_to_hdfstore"

    def do_stuff(self):
        ...
        value = self.hangar(some_function)
        ...
```

And `some_function` will be run inside the context manager. If you need to make the context manager itself generic, and not always "pandas.HDFStore", you can put one more level on the decorator do configure that.

Answer (score 3):

Accepted answer is correct, but having similar issue I opted for creating a property which is also a context manager. So the idea is to use the attribute as a context manager **always**.

In your case:

```
@property
def hangar(self):
    return pandas.HDFStore(...)
```

then you use `with`:

```
with self.hangar as hangar:
   res = some_function(hangar)
```

This allows you to change `hangar` definition (e.g. in a subclass) for something that is not a context manager. In that case, you need to decorate your method:

```
@property
@contextmanager
def hangar(self):
    yield self._hangar
```

and it still be working. Keep in mind that decorator order **matters**, as `yield` instead of `return`.